# Is it possible to have buttons take the appearance of links in a jQuery Mobile Listview?

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I'm trying to create a Listview that contains a mix of buttons and links. Is there any additions/adjustments I can make to the markup to have buttons appear the same as links? At this stage, I'm trying to do as much as I can in markup and not custom CSS (or JS!)

The [markup I'm using](https://jsfiddle.net/33wjq/2/) is:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
    <li>
        <form action="#">
            <button type="submit">Publish</button>
        </form>
    </li>
    <li>
        <form action="#">
            <button type="submit">Delete</button>
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I'd like is this:

[image: Listview]
<sub>(source: [reb4.me](http://reb4.me/x/listview-20140410-194734.png))</sub>

I only seem able to get this:

[image: Listview bad]
<sub>(source: [reb4.me](http://reb4.me/x/listview-bad-20140410-194948.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it.

**jQM 1.4**

To get the arrow icons on the right, add the classes `ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r` to the buttons:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li><a href="#">Edit</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <form action="#">
            <button type="submit" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">Publish</button>
        </form>
    </li>
    <li>
        <form action="#">
            <button type="submit" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">Delete</button>
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then to remove the extra padding, borders, shadows etc. add this CSS:

```
.ui-li-static {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.ui-li-static form button {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/S57Nb/)**

**jQM 1.3**

If you are stuck with jQM 1.3 it is a little more complicated:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li><a href="#">Edit</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <form action="#">
            <button type="submit" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">Publish</button>
        </form>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow fakeLinkIcon">&nbsp;</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <form action="#">
            <button type="submit" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">Delete</button>
        </form>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow fakeLinkIcon">&nbsp;</span>
    </li>
</ul>

.ui-li-static {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.fakeLinkIcon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -9px;
}
.ui-li-static form div.ui-submit{
    padding-right: 2.5em;
}
.ui-li-static form div.ui-submit {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border: 0;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.ui-li-static form div.ui-submit .ui-btn-inner{
    padding-left: 15px;  
}
.ui-last-child form div.ui-submit {
     border-bottom-right-radius: 16px;   
     border-bottom-left-radius: 16px;   
}
.ui-first-child form div.ui-submit {
     border-top-right-radius: 16px;   
     border-top-left-radius: 16px;   
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/S57Nb/2/)**

Comment: Thks, too bad it can't be done using only markup. Instead I've opted for a link that reveals the button—has the added benefit of protecting against errantly altering a resource.